# Backref for sets - unwanted different formatting

Tags: biblatex, back-referencing

I'm trying to polish my thesis with a nice bibliography (with `biblatex`, `backend=bibtex`) but I have a problem with the way the backreferences are treated with respect to sets of references.

Indeed, I use `@set` to group two papers within the same entry (say a paper and an erratum, or two papers by the same set of people on the same thing).
The issue then is that the `backref` does not look the same for a single paper or for a set of papers: the former is between brackets (as I would like) and the latter is not.
Also, I would like all of those to be on the next line.

See:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{changepage}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=numeric-comp, sorting=none, backref=true, backrefsetstyle=setonly, maxcitenames=3, maxbibnames=10]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{}
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addspace}
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}
  \printfield{volume}
  \printfield{number}
}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{author}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{volume}{{\bf #1}}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  backrefpage = {\uppercase{s}ee p\adddot},
  backrefpages = {\uppercase{s}ee pp\adddot},
}

\addbibresource{Biblio-Dismantled}

\begin{document}

One may have a MOND at such scales~\cite{Milgrom1983set}. MOND theories have been embedded in relativistic modified gravitational field theories, the so-called \emph{Te}nsor-\emph{Ve}ctor-\emph{S}calar (TeVeS) theories of gravity~\cite{Bekenstein2004}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

with the `.bib` file:

```
@string{AJ="The Astrophysical Journal"}
@string{PRD="Physical Review D"}

@set{Milgrom1983set,
entryset =  { Milgrom1983-1, Milgrom1983-2 } 
}

@article{Milgrom1983-1,
    entryset =  { Milgrom1983set },
    author =    { M. Milgrom },
    title =     { A Modification of the Newtonian dynamics as a possible alternative to the hidden mass hypothesis },
    journaltitle =  AJ,
    year =      { 1983 },
    volume =    { 270 },
    pages =     { 365 }
}

@article{Milgrom1983-2,
    entryset =  { Milgrom1983set },
    author =    { \\ },
    title =     { A Modification of the Newtonian dynamics: Implications for galaxies },
    journaltitle =  AJ,
    year =      { 1983 },
    volume =    { 270 },
    pages =     { 371 }
}

@article{Bekenstein2004,
author =    { J. D. Bekenstein },
title =     { Relativistic gravitation theory for the MOND paradigm },
journaltitle =  PRD,
year =      { 2004 },
volume =    { 70 },
number =    { 08 },
pages =     { 083509 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two macros, `setpageref` for backrefs in `@set`s and `pageref` for all other types. They look very different save for one line where they differ by a `[parens]` in the optional argument to `\printtext`.
The simple line

```
\renewbibmacro*{setpageref}{\usebibmacro{pageref}}
```

should be enough to make the two macros behave the same. (I have no idea why the two formats are different...)

---

You can get a new line before the backreferences with

```
\renewcommand*{\bibpagerefpunct}{\newline}
```

`@set`s don't use `\bibpagerefpunct` by default, so we have to modify the driver to also use `\bibpagerefpunct`.

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{set}{%
  \entryset{}{}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}%
  \usebibmacro{setpageref}%
  \finentry}
```

Comment: That is great, thanks a lot! As usual, so simple yet not found after so much time spent on it.

Anyway, do you have an idea to put it on the next line as well?
Thanks again,

Comment: @Thomas Check the edit, please.

Comment: Awesome! Would you mind explaining it quickly? I understand the first line but not the \Declare...
Also, what if I'm picky and ultimately I'd like to have the backrefs on a new line for sets only, but not for single entries?

Comment: Actually managed to do it: replace
\renewcommand*{\bibpagerefpunct}{\newline}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{set}{%
  \entryset{}{}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}%
  \usebibmacro{setpageref}%
  \finentry}
with
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{set}{%
  \entryset{}{}%
  \setunit{\newline}%
  \usebibmacro{setpageref}%
  \finentry}
Thanks again :)